# Get data from JSON dynamically

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a json like this:

```
{
   listOfOptions:[
     {
       valueType: "alphabet"
       possibleValues:["a","b"]
     },
     {
       valueType: "integer"
       possibleValues:["1","2"]
     }
   ]
```

I am getting these value name dynamically so in my react function i want the corresponding possible values:

so i created a function like this:

```
myjson.listOfOptions.map((item,index)=> {
    if(item.valueType==e)
      return item.possibleValues[0]
})
```

so when running this if I set "e" as an integer, then I am getting:
`[null,"1"]`
But what I want is: 
`"1"` (only "1" not ["1"])

Can I use filter to get expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the resultant array returned by `Array.map` will be the same length as the input array. For the first object in your input array, the callback function returns `null`.

So, I think what're you're looking for is something like this;

### Original answer

```
myjson.listOfOptions
  .filter(item => item.valueType==e) // get just the items that match your filter condition
  .map(item => item.possibleValue[0]) // then get the sub attribute's values
```

### Edited (after question in comments)

```
// get the first object that matches the search condition
let result = myjson.listOfOptions.find(item => item.valueType==e) 
// this will return the first element in the array `possibleValues` of that object that matches the search condition
return result.possibleValues[0];
```

> **pro tip:** use something like lodash for safe navigation; so the return statement looks something like `_.get(result, 'possibleValues[0]', 'N/A')`

Comment: thanks this is useful, i was able to remove null but i am getting ["1"] but what I want is "1"

Comment: then you don't want to use `map` because it will always return an array. Maybe you'll want to use `find`, i've edited my answer with this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
let result = [];

myjson.listOfOptions.forEach((item,index) => {
    if(item.valueType == e)
      result.push(item.possibleValues[0]);
})

console.log('result', result);
```

Or use **[array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)**:

```
result = myjson.listOfOptions.reduce((result, item, index)=> {
    if(item.valueType == e){
      result.push(item.possibleValues[0]);
    }
    return result;
}, [])
```